# How should I set up my partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a dual boot set up with XP (I know it's ancient but I have a favored game that won't work on anything newer) and Ubuntu 12.10. Both OSs are on a 70gb HDD and I have a 300gb HDD as well. 
I have a Dell Dimension 3000 with a pentium 4 2.80ghz CPU and 1.2gb of RAM.

My current partition set up is as follows: on the 70gb HDD I have ~32.1gb ntfs for windows, 42.3gb ext2 for Ubuntu, and 1mb for the Swap.
The 300gb is all ntfs, but has plenty of room to change and I can easily back up my Ubuntu data there if I have to make changes.

What would be a good way to set up my partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main partitions for Windows and Ubuntu look fine, but I would make your swap a bit more. Swap partitions should be >= the amount of physical RAM you have installed. If you want to resize your partitions, I recommend using a GParted Live CD.

You can download the .iso for GParted [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php). Then, burn it to a DVD, and boot into GParted.

Comment: I can understand that suspend-to-disk requires swap >= RAM, but why did you write "at least twice the amount of RAM"?

Comment: That was useful, thanks. I'll have to keep this CD handy.

Comment: I think the ***2x swap space*** rule came from Old Solaris and Windows admins. Also, earlier memory mangers were very badly designed. There were not very smart. Today, we have very smart and intelligent memory manager for both Linux and UNIX. [Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-swap-space.html).

Comment: GParted is usually very useful for me. :)